# What makes a simple graph?

Tags: graph

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/r25b4.png)

1.) Is the graph simple? Why or why not? What is the degree of the vertex b?

2.) Does the graph have an Eulerian circuit or path? Give theoretical reasons for your answer.
If it does have such a circuit or path, exhibit it by showing the starting, intermediate, and ending vertices.

3.) Does the graph have a Hamiltonian circuit or path? Give theoretical reasons for your answer. If it does have such a circuit or path, exhibit it by showing the starting, intermediate, and ending vertices.

4.) Show that the graph satisfies Euler’s formula.

Comment: Stackoverflow isn't a forum for you to have homework problems solved. Further, this doesn't seem to be a question related to computer programming, but rather related to graph theory.

Comment: It is somewhat related to computer programming, I'm just not getting some of it... For example how would I give a theoretical reason in question 2 and 3? These are only practice questions that i took from my book "Rosen's Discrete Mathematics and its Applications"